# How is 「ように」 different to just 「よう」?

Tags: nuances

*When writing or reading a sentence in Japanese, does the word 「よう」 have a nuance any different to using 「ように」?*

**For example, sentences using 「ように」:**

好きなように踊ってよろしい。

落第しないように一生懸命勉強しなさい。

君の将来が幸せでありますように。

ちょっと怒ったようにきこえた。

**For example, sentences using 「よう」:**

まるでボスのような話し方をする。

君は自分のためになるような書物を読べきだ。

<strike>ここには、誰もいないだよ。</strike>

映画を見たようです。

学生のようだ。

Comment: Perhaps it would help to understand ように as made up of よう, and the particle に. And the choice of what comes after よう depends on the rest of the sentence and what you wish to convey.

Comment: And it's also a question of grammar changing 学生のようだ to 学生のようにだ would be wrong. (Unless you interpret it as 「学生のように」、だ。)

Comment: You don't appear to be comparing ように against よう.  Instead, you appear to be comparing ように against ような and ようだ・ようです.

Answer (score 9):

Does it help if I tell you that ～よう mostly behaves like a な-adjective, so identically to 静か or 綺麗? That is, its attributive form is ような, its adverbial form is ように, its declarative form is ようだ, and so on.

It is modified just like usual nouns and な-adjectives in noun roles: 人間のよう, こんなよう, 好きなよう, 楽しいよう, 話せるよう, and so on.

This よう is actually secretly 様. See also [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/226613/m0u/).

Comment: I also recommend this really good in-depth analysis of な-adjectives, specifically this part which explains the various inflections of よう and そう with examples: https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2018/11/na-adjectives.html#suffixes-that-are-na-adjective

Answer (score 2):

ような = adjectival
ように = adverbial

ようだ(ようです) = seem