# Is it grammatically correct to use よう without な, に or だ（です）after it?

Tags: grammar

> 神の思し召しであなたとよき友情を育むためにあなたにメールする**よう**お告げがありました

I think the sentence roughly translates into: "For the sake of raising you and good friend into God's thoughts, you mailed a divine message"

Instincts tell me that there should be a な or に before/after the よう in the sentence

I found some pages on the net discussing the proper usage of よう in a sentence from [this site](http://maggiesensei.com/2012/04/03/request-lesson-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86you/) and [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/similar.html). All of the examples had ような、ように、なよう, and によう.

I did come across [a sample](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12397/how-is-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB-different-to-just-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86) that was written as 話せるよう. The thing that has left me confused is that nothing came after よう.

Was I right to suspect this sentence as being grammatically incorrect or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: According to [this page](http://homepage3.nifty.com/transjaws/qa21.htm), the translation should be "God touches mind and asked me to write to you for a good friendship with you."

Comment: It sounds a bit "engrishy", don't you think? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES, That is right.

> "メールするよう(に)お告げがありました"

"に" is optional.
Here, "ように" or "よう" is used in the sense of such instructions or request.

or

> "メールするよう(に との)お告げがありました"
>   "メールするよう(に という)お告げがありました"

**as other example**

> "上司から今すぐ帰社するよう(に)連絡がありました"
>   "医者に規則正しい生活を送るよう(に)言われました"